# Weird parallel collection behavior

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use scala parallel collections to implement some cpu-intensive
task, I've wanted to abstract the way the algorithm can be executed
(sequentially, parallel or even distributed), but the code dosn't work as I
would suspect and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

The way I wanted to abstract this problem is mocked below:

```
// just measures time a block of code runs
def time(block: => Unit) : Long = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  block
  val stop = System.currentTimeMillis
  stop - start
}

// "lengthy" task
def work = {
  Thread.sleep(100)
  println("done")
  1
}

import scala.collection.GenSeq


abstract class ContextTransform {
  def apply[T](genSeq: GenSeq[T]): GenSeq[T]
}

object ParContextTransform extends ContextTransform {
  override def apply[T](genSeq: GenSeq[T]): GenSeq[T] = genSeq.par
}

// this works as expected
def callingParDirectly = {
  val range = (1 to 10).par

  // make sure we really got a ParSeq
  println(range) 
  for (i <- range) yield work
}

// this doesn't 
def callingParWithContextTransform(contextTransform: ContextTransform) = {
  val range = contextTransform(1 to 10)

  // make sure we really got a ParSeq
  println(range)
  for (i <- range) yield work
}
```

The result from the interpreter:

```
scala> time(callingParDirectly)
ParRange(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
done
// ...
done
res20: Long = 503

scala> time(callingParWithContextTransform(ParContextTransform))
ParRange(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
done
// ...
done
res21: Long = 1002
```

My first bet was that the collection doesn't split properly and the println's of
"done" indeed suggest that... but the above code works well if I don't yield
anything (just run the work method).

I can't understand why the `callingParWithContextTransform` method doesn't work
like `callingParDirectly`; what am I missing?

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? This looks like one bug that was previously reported.

Comment: I can reproduce this with 2.9.1.RC3.

Comment: I _thought_ the bug was closed on trunk, but, as one can see, it isn't. Good thing I did not blithely state it has been fixed. :-) Though I confess the only reason I did not say so was that 2.9.1 is not out yet -- I thought it was fixed there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible culprit: [SI-4843](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4843).

Answer (score 6):

Daniel Sobral is right, this is a known bug. I can reproduce your results with Scala 2.9.1.RC3, but it's fixed in trunk. Here's a simplified version that demonstrates the slowdown:

```
  // just measures time a block of code runs
  def time(block: => Unit) : Long = {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      block
      val stop = System.currentTimeMillis
      stop - start
  }

  // "lengthy" task
  def work = {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      1
  }

  def run() {
    import scala.collection.GenSeq

    print("Iterating over ParRange: ")
    println(time(for (i <- (1 to 10).par) yield work))

    print("Iterating over GenSeq: ")
    println(time(for (i <- (1 to 10).par: GenSeq[Int]) yield work))
  }

  run()
```

The output I get on 2.9.1.RC3 is

```
Iterating over ParRange: 202
Iterating over GenSeq: 1002
```

but on a nightly build of 2.10, both versions run in about 200ms.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll start looking into the nighties